# How do you make a partial in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, renderpartial

I'm trying to figure out how to make and use a partial in react. I've figured out how to make a new page, but now I'm trying to put my footer in a partial and add it to my page layout.

I have a page layout - I'm trying to add the footer here:

```
import React from 'react'
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import Logo from '../assets/logo.png'
import '../styles/PageLayout.scss'
var Footer = require('Footer');


export const PageLayout = ({ children }) => (
  <div className='container text-center'>
    <NavLink to='/' activeClassName='page-layout__nav-item--active'><img className='icon' src={Logo} /></NavLink>

    <div className='page-layout__viewport'>
      {children}
      <Footer />
    </div>

    </div>


  </div>


)
PageLayout.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node,
}

export default PageLayout
```

Then I have a components/Footer.js which has:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
// import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import * as ReactBootstrap from 'react-bootstrap'

class Footer extends React.Component {

  render: function () {
      return (
        testing
      );
    }
  }

  module.exports = Footer;

}
```

This gives an error that says:

```
ERROR in ./src/components/PageLayout.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'Footer' in '/Users/me/code/learn-react-redux/src/components'
 @ ./src/components/PageLayout.js 26:13-30
 @ ./src/routes/index.js
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi ./src/main webpack-hot-middleware/client.js?path=/__webpack_hmr
```

Does anyone know how to incorporate a partial into a page layout. There isn't anything dynamic to put in there - I'm just trying (and failing miserably) to extract a partial and keep my file tidy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see <s>two</s> three errors in your Footer.

1. Your render() function must return an element, not bare text. i.e. `<span>testing</span>` NOT `testing`.
2. Your export statement sits inside your class definition. Place it outside.
3. **UPDATE** Your render function signature should read `render() {`

Finally, your require statement also looks wrong. Try `require('./Footer')`.

Comment: Thanks David, When I try these changes I then get an error that says: Error: Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (8:10) [0m [90m 6 | [39m[36mclass[39m [33mFooter[39m [36mextends[39m [33mReact[39m[33m.[39m[33mComponent[39m { [90m 7 | [39m [31m[1m>[22m[39m[90m 8 | [39m render[33m:[39m [36mfunction[39m () { [90m | [39m [31m[1m^[22m[39m [90m 9 | [39m [36mreturn[39m ( [90m 10 | [39m [33m<[39m[33mspan[39m[33m>[39mtesting[33m<[
Object../src/components/Footer.js
http://localhost:3000/main.js:6523:7

Comment: Try changing `render: function () {` to `render() {`

Comment: Thank you. So hard to find the syntax. I've taken 4 different udemy classes on react and each of them has a system that doesnt seem to work.